# Cannot found entity after add form in Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-forms

I have three entity (Activite, CabinetEquipe and ActiviteEquipe). When I add Activite, I want to add many CabinetEquipe in ActiviteEquipe.

**CabinetEquipe entity**

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="libelle", type="string", nullable=false, length=125)
 */
private $libelle;
```

**Activite entity**

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="LogicielBundle\Entity\ActiviteEquipe", mappedBy="activite", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
private $equipes;

public function addEquipe(\LogicielBundle\Entity\ActiviteEquipe $equipe)
{
    $this->equipes[] = $equipe;
    $equipe->setActivite($this);
    return $this;
}

public function removeEquipe(\LogicielBundle\Entity\ActiviteEquipe $equipe)
{
    $this->equipes->removeElement($equipe);
}

public function getEquipes()
{
    return $this->equipes;
}
```

**ActiviteEquipe entity**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UtilisateurBundle\Entity\CabinetEquipe")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $equipe;

public function setEquipe(\UtilisateurBundle\Entity\CabinetEquipe $equipe)
{
    $this->equipe = $equipe;

    return $this;
}

public function getEquipe()
{
    return $this->equipe;
}
```

But, after my form for add **Activite**, I have this error :  **Found entity of type UtilisateurBundle\Entity\CabinetEquipe on association LogicielBundle\Entity\Activite#equipes, but expecting LogicielBundle\Entity\ActiviteEquipe**

**My Form :**

```
        $builder->add('equipes', 'entity', array(
            'label' => 'Équipe(s)',
            'class' => 'UtilisateurBundle\Entity\CabinetEquipe',
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => true,
            'choices' => $equipes,
            'property' => function($equipe) {
                return $equipe->getLibelle();
            }
        ));
```

Can you help me pleases ? I'm newbie in Symfony

Answer (score 2):

You expect `\LogicielBundle\Entity\ActiviteEquipe` in your entity.

```
public function addEquipe(\LogicielBundle\Entity\ActiviteEquipe $equipe)
{
```

But in form you work on `\UtilisateurBundle\Entity\CabinetEquipe`.

```
$builder->add('equipes', 'entity', array(
    'label' => 'Équipe(s)',
    'class' => 'UtilisateurBundle\Entity\CabinetEquipe',
```

In form you need to choose entity which is expected in **addEquipe** and **removeEquipe**.

Looks like you expect some kind of proxy (**ActiviteEquipe**) which is imo not needed here.